# emit signal of class from different thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

My class have a friend class member with name mythread, and i emit the signal of parent class in run method of MyThread class, but nothing happened and connected slots to myclass didn't call.

```
class ActorT : public QObject {
     Q_OBJECT
   public:
     ActorT() { thre = new MyThread(this); }
   signals:
     void sendTest();
   public slots:
     void start() { thre->start(); }
     void wait() { thre->wait(); }
   private:
     MyThread* thre;
};

class MyThread : public QThread {
public:
   MyThread(ActorT* parent) { mc = parent }    
   void run() { 
      for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
      {
          emit mc->sendTest();
          msleep(10);
      }
   }

   ActorT* mc;
};

class Test : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
 public:
      Test() { i = 0; }
 public slots:
    void times() { printf("%d \n", ++i); }
 private:
    int i;
}

int main() {
     QCoreApplication app;
     ActorT a;
     Test t;
     QObject::connect(&a, SIGNAL(sendTest()), &t, SLOT(times()));
     a.start();
     a.wait(); // this line is wrong part
     return app.exec();
}
```

I don't understand whats wrong with this implementation?

Update: i know whats wrong now, thanks a lot.

Comment: What version of Qt?  As of 4.7 (or maybe 4.8) you don't need to subclass QThread.  Properly connect it and use QObject::sendToThread().

Comment: How is mc defined? Is it a member of MyThread?

Comment: @kiss-o-matic: there is no such a thing as sentToThread, only moveToThread. Also, it is red herring because it is also a valid way of using QThreads.

Comment: @danics, can you provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)? Currently, for me, it is difficult to help. Your description sounds strange though: `My class have a friend class member with name mythread, and i emit the signal of parent class in run method of MyThread class` because parent means something different. Also, you may want to reconsider your design what signal to emit and from where. Also, the friend declaration seems to be hidden from us, too.

Comment: @lpapp, that's it.  I wrote that before I had my morning coffee.  From what I've read (mostly here) it is the *preferred* way to handle QThread in version >= 4.7.  I've only played with that design a little bit, but it seemed to work for me.

Comment: Thank you all, I find the wrong part. cause the main source is so big i wrote a sample here and update the question for better understanding, anyway i want to implement a Actor pattern somehow. the wait function was the reason of the problem and because i need that wait function i think i should use function pointer instead of signal and slot pattern